# Get input with IdaPython

Tags: ida, idapython

How can I get input from user with IdaPython?

When I tried `str = input()` ,I got error `RuntimeError: input(): lost.sys.stdin`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ask_*` functions from the [`ida_kernwin` module](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_kernwin-module.html).

For example:

- `ask_long`: Display a dialog box and wait for the user to input an number
- `ask_str`: Display a dialog box and wait for the user to input a text string
- `ask_file`: Display a dialog box and wait for the user to input a file name
- `ask_form`: Display a dialog box and wait for the user

There are also the `choose_*` functions if you want the user to choose something from the database (function, segment, structure). And fully customisable forms (see [this example](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/widgets/forms/askusingform.py)).

Comment: how do I install `ida_kernwin` ? is there a build in option to get string without install module?

Comment: The `ida_kernwin` module is part of IDAPython. Try pasting the following code into the interpreter in the *Output window*: `ida_kernwin.ask_str("Default value", 0, "Please enter string")`

Comment: I tried `import ida_kerwin` and I get ` No moudle named 'ida_kerwin'`

Comment: `ida_kernwin`, not `ida_kerwin`, and it should already be imported